# How to change directory/open a Python program?

Tags: python, putty, intel-edison

I'm coding Python for my edison board using putty. I have a Python file which I wish to run on my edison board (simple blink LED). The .py file is located in a folder called "pythonpractice" in my documents on my C drive. I've been trying to change directory doing like "cd \ documents" etc. but to of no avail. (my edison board is set up correctly).

If anyone could just show me how I could go about opening the Python file in putty I have in my documents I would be very grateful!

Comment: Subprocess might be useful resource

Comment: I assume you are confused by what putty does and where you are. With putty you are *working* on the Edison Board. You don't have a c:\ drive there and you can't access your files on your PC directly (at least not without effort). You'll need to go over how to use SSH with your files. This might help to get you [started](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/edison-getting-started-guide#ssh-ing-into-the-edison). If that is not the problem then please add extra details what where you're stuck.

Comment: hello rene thanks for the reply. I did not really word myself correctly there, I am aware that with putty you are working directly on the edison board itself but for some reason i thought i still could access my windows files from the edison board which after reading your comment i realised was quite the silly assumption! that has cleared a lot up for me. Might just load the program onto an SD card then plug the SD card into the edison. thanks rene!